# How to add the RGB values of an image together

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, rgb, pixel

I need to add together the three values for red, green and blue of a pixel together so that I can be able to find the average value of the pixel colour. However I do not know how to extract the three values since they are not being held in an array.

I am loading an image from the computer's memory and analysing each pixel in order to find the amount of pure white pixels in the image, however I wish to convert this into a value between 1 and 0 so that I may create a neural network following this. Is there a way for me to add these three values together?

My code is:

```
pix = newimage2.load()

print(newimage2.size)

print(" ")

whitevalues = 0

for x in range(0, newimage2.width):

    for y in range(0, newimage2.height):

        if pix[x,y] == (255,255,255):

            whitevalues = whitevalues + 1

print(whitevalues)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Write an answer since I'm not able to comment. Use the getpixel-function. In your loop:

```
r, g, b = image.getpixel( (x, y) )
added_together = r + g + b
```

Documentation here: http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/Image.html